# Reveal a picture piece by piece

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reveal a picture piece by piece. I found this thread here [need ideas to only display some pixels and gray out the remaining pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957789/need-ideas-to-only-display-some-pixels-and-gray-out-the-remaining-pixels), with an excellent answer from mVChr. This is almost what I'm looking for, but I would like to make the revealing pieces larger, so it takes less time to completely see the image.
What do I have to adapt in the code?
Anybody able to help me?
Thanks a lot for the effort

Comment: I think it's the parts where it says `var += 3`, change that to a larger number.

Comment: Something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/nwPy5/ It reveals/hides blocks of the image when you hover.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock Also in the inline style for the `div` which gets added.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change two things.

First is the size of the grey boxes. That is done with this

```
htmlFrag += '<div id="'+id+'" class="pix" ' +
            'style="width:3px;height:3px;position:absolute;' +
            'left:'+j+'px;top:'+i+'px;"></div>';
```

Into something like this

```
htmlFrag += '<div id="'+id+'" class="pix" ' +
            'style="width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;' +
            'left:'+j+'px;top:'+i+'px;"></div>';
```

Then you need to change the for loop that puts the boxes in to match

```
for (var i = 0, len = $('#i').height(); i < len; i += 3) {
    for (var j = 0, len = $('#i').width(); j < len; j += 3) {
```

Turns into

```
for (var i = 0, len = $('#i').height(); i < len; i += 10) {
    for (var j = 0, len = $('#i').width(); j < len; j += 10) {
```

[Here's the example !](http://jsfiddle.net/W7Xse/41/)

Comment: Beaten to the punch :) Made a small adaption to the original fiddle to put the size in a variable so you can test easily: http://jsfiddle.net/W7Xse/42/  (change the pixelsize var)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [branch of corsiKa's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfHSM/5/) with some mods, most significant of which is the way the pixels are removed, allowing a time period to be specified.

The need for the pixels to have ids is also avoided, therefore the HTML is simpler.